# How to reduce the frequency of hangfire calls to the database?

Tags: c#, hangfire

I have a background service web app using C# and hangfire. I notice that just in a short duration, for example, 1 minute, there are around 800 calls to the database by hangfire. Note that I have no yet created any request job or recurring job in the hangfire. Is there a way to reduce the frequency of hangfire calls to the database?

I have set to just 1 worker and `QueuePollInterval` to `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120)` but not sure why there are 3 calls to the db every 2 seconds.

```
var options = new SqlServerStorageOptions
{
    QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120)
};

builder.Services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
    .UseSqlServerStorage(myServicesConnStr, options)
    .UseFilter(new AutomaticRetryAttribute { Attempts = 1, DelaysInSeconds = new int[] { 1800 } })
);

builder.Services.AddHangfireServer(options => options.WorkerCount = 1);
```

Comment: are you sure they are from hangfire ? some database screenshots would be helpful

Comment: As far as I remember, it highly depends on your polling interval, each roundtrip was like 20+ queries. As I wanted something quite reactive without interfering with my DB Server, I switched to the Redis Storage (pro license) version

Comment: @CodingMytra, yes they are from hangfire. jbl, yeah, I believe it is the polling interval. After I configure to QueuePollInterval to TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), looks like the calls to db reduced. But, there are will calls to db every 2-3 minutes. I thought it will be every 10 minutes.

Comment: I guess the queries you see every 2-3 minutes are issued by the background task server, signalling it is still alive and available to process data

Comment: @jbl, it's every 2 second, 4 calls to the db. How do I configure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traces from database would be nice to have some visibility.
My best bet would be that those calls are coming from Dashboard or heartbeats.

Look into following properties (and their current values) to reduce calls:

- HeartbeatInterval
- ServerCheckInterval
- SchedulePollingInterval
- StatsPollingInterval

References: https://api.hangfire.io/html/Properties_T_Hangfire_Server_BackgroundProcessingServerOptions.htm
https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-sql-server.html#configuring-the-polling-interval

Comment: Hi I have tried all of them but still no success.